# Correct way of using SVG in HTML File

Tags: html, css, frontend

What is the correct way to add SVG my HTML File?
Is it Good to add SVG directly to the HTML file using `<svg>` tag instead of using another method as doing this way makes the HTML file much lengthier ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic..

Answer (score 2):

You can either paste the svg code directly into the html or link to it via an external file.

```html
<!-- paste it directly -->
<svg>...</svg>

<!-- external file -->
<img src="something.svg" />
```

There are advantages to both. So it depends on what you want to do with it.

If you link to an external file, then the file will be cached in the users browser on future visits to any page that uses it.

If you paste the code directly, you can change the properties of the SVG with CSS

```css
.someSvgClass {
    fill: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree, and if you need to animate the SVG through Javascript you should paste directly into the HTML